# JSON deserialization error while restoring Firefox session

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My Firefox session is lost and can't be restored for some reasons. I'm trying to get all the links from the session.json file. I need only URLs and the page titles, not favicons, visit dates etc.

**My code:**

```
string url = string.Empty;
string title = string.Empty;
int cw = 1, ct = 1; //current window, current tab in the current window
Rootobject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(textBox1.Text);
MessageBox.Show("Test");
textBox1.Clear();
foreach (var w in root.windows)
{
   foreach (var t in w.tabs[0].formdata.id.sessionData.windows[0].tabs)
   {
       url = t.entries[0].url;
       title = t.entries[0].title;
       textBox1.Text += cw.ToString() + " - " + ct.ToString() + " - " + url + " - " + title + Environment.NewLine;
       ct++;                
    }
    cw++;
 }
```

And I get the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected
>   delimiter: ". Path
>   'windows[0].tabs[0].formdata.id.sessionData.windows[0].tabs[39].entries[0].triggeringPrincipal_base64',
>   line 1, position 32767.

What may it be? All the previous tabs #0-38 have been deserialized in a proper way.
Also, is there any way to instruct the deserializer something like "just deserialize only 'Url' and 'title' fields in the t.entries[0] and skip the other one"?

Thanks.

Comment: Why Firefox, works in Chrome/IE?

Comment: Did your session.json file get truncated, perhaps?  Try running the JSON through a validator like https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @BrianRogers checked now, it's validate json.